# How to split current directory

Tags: perl, path

I need to get the trailing part of the current directory into a variable. I can do a:

```
use Cwd;
my $dir = getcwd;
```

to get the full path of: `usr\bjm\scPDB_entries\4dpt`, but what I really need is the `4dpt` to be split out from the rest of the path.

Answer (score 5):

[File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)

```
use File::Basename qw(basename);
print basename($dir), "\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

It is best to use [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec), especially if the code is required to work across platforms. The documentation for `File::Basename` says this.

> If your concern is just parsing paths it is safer to use File::Spec's splitpath() and splitdir() methods.

This program does what you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;

my $cwd = File::Spec->rel2abs;
my @path = File::Spec->splitdir($cwd);
my $dir = $path[-1];
print $dir;
```

It long-winded mainly because of the object-oriented nature of `File::Spec`. The helper module [`File::Spec::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec%3a%3aFunctions) allows you to make it more concise, by importing the class methods as local subroutines.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions qw/ rel2abs splitdir /;

my $dir = (splitdir(rel2abs))[-1];
print $dir;
```